# Capturing the Send Dialog information in FB.ui() when Send button is pressed

Tags: jquery, facebook, dhtml

The documentation for the **Facebook Send Dialog** states that the *'to'* parameter can contain a user ID or username. Once the dialog comes up the user can also add email addresses.

Is there a way to **specify an email address at startup time** (documentation suggests no), or is there a clever workaround (**DOM manipulation via jQuery maybe?**) to insert an email address once the dialog is shown?

**Edit:**
I have been able to manually inject the following code into the onclick handler of the 'Send' button in the dialog:

```
var x=document.getElementById('feedform_user_message'); alert(x.value);
```

So now when I click 'Send', the alert window correctly shows me the message text!

Next steps:

1. inject the code automatically (jQuery maybe?)
2. also capture the contents of the To: field
3. call web service to record the action

Comment: Would you mind posting details on how you were able to hook onto the onClick handler for the 'Send' button?

Comment: the question is interesting, but as DustMason says, it would be useful if you give some details on how you solved this.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a script to send Facebook private messages into many users independently. It works with me.

```
    <html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

    <body>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    FB.init({appId: '[YOUR APPID HERE]', xfbml: true, cookie: true});
    </script>

    <a href="#" onclick="    
    FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    name: 'Send Private Message',
    to: '[USERNAME1]'
    });
    ">Send Message to [USERNAME1]</a> 

    <a href="#" onclick="    
    FB.ui({        
    method: 'send',
    name: 'Send Private Message',
    to: '[USERNAME2]'
    });
    ">Send Message to [USERNAME2]</a> 


    <a href="#" onclick="    
    FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    name: 'Send Private Message',
    to: '[USERNAME3]'
    });
    ">Send Message to [USERNAME3]</a> 


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: this is not really what was asked as far as I can tell. It's not about popping up multiple dialogues, but figuring out if a user added new friends in the 'to' field once the dialogue is open.